# extract substring between charachters in specific posittion

Tags: shell

I got string as followed:

```
text=\"abcdef\"gfijk\"lmno\"
```

How can I extract the text between last two " - so I will get only lmno ?

I tried to use  & but without success

```
sub_text=${text&\"*}
echo ${sub_text&\"*}
```

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right, I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done with [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

First, delete that final quote with `${var%pattern}`, which removes the shortest match for `pattern` from the end of `$var`:

```
result=${text%'"'}     # result=\"abcdef\"gfijk\"lmno
```

Then, delete everything from the beginning up to the last remaining quote with `${var##pattern}`, which removes the longest match for `pattern` from the *beginning* of `$var`:

```
result=${result##*'"'} # result=lmno
```

...and then you're there:

```
echo "$result"
```

Comment: BINGO! 
Missed the double ##... :(
Thanks